# Field Appears Only with One Condition Not Two

Tags: 2013, list, infopath, infopath-rules

I'm using InfoPath 2013 and trying to hide a field until a drop option in another field is selected.  When I add one condition the field is hidden and appears at the right time.  But when I add a "or" for it to appear for another drop down option neither will work.

Example: 
If "Type" is not equal to Laptop "or" 
If "Type" is not equal to SmartPad

Checked "Hide this control"

"Ok"

**Do you know why if I have one condition it works but if I add another it does not work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Instead of "or" "and" should be used. Thanks